# count how many commits will be merged with a merge command

Tags: git

It is possibile to count how many commit will be merged on master? Suppose that your flow expects that all your commit must be squashed, this information (the number of commits to be merged) allow to avoid merge without squash.

Is it possibile?

Comment: How many commits _will_ be merged, or how many commits already _have_ been merged?

Comment: "will be merged"

Comment: Will you please draw example graphs of commit history for your expected use cases and state what numbers you want to obtain in each case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plumbing `git rev-list` for this purpose:

```
git status
On branch master                                                                                                            
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.                                                                
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)

git rev-list --count master..origin/master
2
```